# Expected value and certain probability of random variable given by a density.

Tags: probability

Random variable $(X,Y)$ has distribution with density $$g(x,y)=Cx(x+y)\mathbb{1}_{\{|y|\leq x\leq 1\}}$$
How to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2|Y|)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$? Since $\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(x,y)=1$ I obtained $C=\frac{6}{5}$. But I have absolutely no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Are you familiar with 2-variable calculus?

Comment: I believe I am.

Comment: Then you need a double integral over $g$ to calculate $C$.

Comment: That's what I did. Oh, there's a typo ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To find the probability $P(X\ge2|Y|)$ integrate the density on the region of the plane that satisfies the equation $X\ge2|Y|$. For the expected value your next step would be finding the conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and then using the definition.

Comment: Sooo, $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 2|Y|)=\frac{6}{5}\int_{0}^{1/2}\int_0^{1}x(x+y)\ dx dy$ ? And how exactly do I find conditional density?

Comment: I believe you are integrating the wrong region. It should be $0\le x\le 1,-x/2\le y\le x/2$. Also, $C=2$. For conditional density, just look up its definition.